# SegmentationFault (11) on Apache (macOS)

Tags: php, apache

I'm getting a segmentation fault on macOS, but only when using PHP from homebrew (tried with 7.2, 7.3). If I switch back to default macOS PHP, it works fine.

```
[Tue Jun 02 22:47:54.220053 2020] [core:notice] [pid 66936] AH00052: child pid 35517 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Jun 02 22:47:55.289187 2020] [core:notice] [pid 66936] AH00052: child pid 35520 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Jun 02 22:49:17.040809 2020] [core:notice] [pid 66936] AH00052: child pid 35521 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Jun 02 22:49:18.116103 2020] [core:notice] [pid 66936] AH00052: child pid 35964 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Jun 02 22:49:19.183073 2020] [core:notice] [pid 66936] AH00052: child pid 35966 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

I tried to dump Apache core, but had no luck. It only happens (as far as I know) on login screens, such as PhpMyAdmin and wp-login.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: random WAG : when you switch php versions, do you update apache config to load the proper phpLib ? obcit : `sudo apachectl -k restart`

Comment: The only time i've encountered a seg fault with php was when `output_buffering` was set to a very low number. While I doubt it will solve your issue, try increasing `output_buffering` to a higher number. Say >= 8192

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Yes, altough I'm not sure if I'm importing from the proper dir. I'm importing from here: ```LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so```

Comment: @Andrei Yeah, I tried to increase ```output_buffering``` or even disabling it, but got no luck.

Comment: @LucasVeiga , yep thats what i got. Another wag, can you check at the cli with php -m the list of modules configured, see if you have a 'missing' module within 7.2 or 7.4 in comparaison to the shipped php.